# On Azure AD portal, where to find "sub" claim value for user that is included in ID Token for authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect

We implemented openid connect authentication in a web application. A customer uses Azure AD as the identity provider, we need to get the "sub"(subject) claim value in the ID Token that is being sent to our web application from Azure AD for mapping with web application user. May I know where could we find this "sub" claim value for user on Azure AD portal? Please advice, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you can find it.
The sub claim contains a unique, immutable identifier for the user for that one app.
Its value is different in other apps for the same user.
So it is possibly computed based on some other identifiers but I am not sure.
But I have never seen it in any API responses or pages in the portal.

If you want to a unique, immutable id that you can look up in the portal, you need to use the oid claim.
This claim contains the objectId for the user, which you can see in the portal when looking at the user details.
It is also the user's id in the Graph API if you need to look them up.

The sub claim works for identifying a user uniquely in an app, but if you need to link them to the user in Azure AD, you should use the oid claim.

More info in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#payload-claims

Comment: I am seeing AzureAD issue ID tokens with neither 'sub' or 'oid' claims in their ID tokens. This is with the optional 'profile' scope specified. Also, I don't see these claims in the list of optional claims that can be added in the AzureAD UI.

Comment: That.. shouldn't be possible. If you have a sample token, could you share it? My Twitter DMs are also open in case you don't want to share it here.

Comment: There is a 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier' claim... could it be that AzureAD is using a different name for the oid claim?

Comment: Yes that's it! It isn't Azure AD that is using a different name, it's the .NET library has default claim mappings for known claims for legacy reasons. You can find the sub claim as well as something similar but ending in "nameidentifier".

Comment: ahh, thank you! In which case I think 'sub' has been mapped to 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier'. I am using the Microsoft.Owin packages in ASP.NET Framework, so I will go look through the source code to find the mappings and learn why they are there, etc.

Comment: For the record, the full set of mappings are defined in package/assembly System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt; here: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/dev/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/ClaimTypeMapping.cs